# WebView scrollTo is not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to use scrollTo method of webview. This my layout file for the webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
>  
<WebView  
   android:id="@+id/webMap"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
 />  
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do is showing a html file (which has only a map image) and scrolling to certain area on image with :

```
mapWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/maps/map.html");
mapWebView.scrollTo(300, 300);
```

But when the webview is loaded it always shows the (0, 0) of the image.

What is the problem with `scrollTo()` here?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737412/android-webview-scrollto-is-not-working/22920457#22920457

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that `mapWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/maps/map.html");` is asynchronous, so  `mapWebView.scrollTo(300, 300);` executes before the webview has finished loading. Once the page loads it will have lost the scroll setting you applied and will be reset to the top.

You need to listen in for the the page loading and then scroll it:

```
mapWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mapWebView.scrollTo(300, 300);
        }

    }
    );
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: Turns out this is unreliable, use this instead:

```
mapWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
             mapWebView.scrollTo(300, 300);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dean. I also tried it, but still not working. However, after scrollTo() i called getScrollX() and getScrollY() to see what they return and it is (300, 300). But the image is still on (0, 0).

Comment: Try the other code I posted, looks like the finished loading method sometimes fires before page is actually loaded especially if you have images which you do

Answer (score 2):

**Try this..:**

```
 try {
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,
            int newProgress) {

        if (newProgress >= 100) {

            webview.scrollTo(x,y);
        }

        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    };

});
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyViewClient myViewClient = new MyViewClient();


    // Обработка переворачивания экрана и начальная инициализация выбранной темы (ID_TOPIC) в приложении
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Вторичное создание окна после переворачивания экрана
        scrollTopic = savedInstanceState.getFloat(SCROOL_TOPIC, 0);
    } else {
        // Первый запуск программы до переворачивания экрана
        // Чтение данных с настроек программы
        scrollTopic = sPref.getFloat(SCROOL_TOPIC, 0);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(myViewClient);


// Сохранение данных в буфер при переворачивании экрана
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putFloat(SCROOL_TOPIC, getScrollWebView()); // Сохраняем вертикальную прокрутку
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

// Метод при закрытии окна
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Сохранение настроек программы в файл настроек
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putFloat(SCROOL_TOPIC, getScrollWebView());
    ed.apply();
}

// Класс собственного загрузчика html
public class MyViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    // Переопределение метода окончания загрузки страницы
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        setScrolling();
    }
}

// Установка нужной прокрутки в нашем webView
private void setScrolling() {
    final WebView newView = webView;
    try {
        if (scrollTopic > 0) {
            newView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (newView.getProgress() >= 100) {
                        newView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                newView.scrollTo(0, (int) getScrollingFromPercentage());
                                scrollTopic = 0;
                            }
                        }, 10);
                    } else {
                        newView.post(this);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}

// Определение процента прокрутки (без умножения на 100)
private float getScrollWebView() {
    return (float) (webView.getScrollY() - webView.getTop()) / webView.getContentHeight();
}

// Определение прокрутки по проценту (без деления на 100)
private float getScrollingFromPercentage() {
    return webView.getTop() + scrollTopic * webView.getContentHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following override works better for me.

```
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
 // set initial scroll to
 scrollTo(yourXpos,yourYpos);
 super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little kludgy, but it works.  Use javascript with DOM in `onPageFinished` to describe where you want to start.  I originally implemented it to move to a specified anchor after the page loaded.  If there is no anchor, I need it to go to the top of the page, so I just look for the '`html`' tag.

```
        //Perform operations when page finishes loading
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            if (anchor != null)
                webHelp.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"$anchor\").scrollIntoView()")
            else
                webHelp.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].scrollIntoView()")
        }
```