# How to scroll WebView to top in android?

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I am working on a webView in an app, where content which webview load changes when a button is pressed (two buttons next and previous , they just change the content in webview).

If I scroll down to a point in webview and press next or previous button it starts from the same point. I just want that everytime the new data is loaded to webview it display the content from the top.
I have used:

```
webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But doesnt work.How can it work ?Please help anyone?

Comment: answered here check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392031/webview-scrollto-is-not-working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a webviewclient and set the onPageFinished to scroll to the top:
[How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android)

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});
```

That way, the content will be loaded when you scroll. It may feel a bit sluggish, but it should work every time.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe delaying it would work? as the content doesn't usualy load instantly

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.scrollTo(0,0);

            }
        }, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use thread and delay the scrollTo to make it work