# Android webView focus on specific part of image

Tags: android, webview, focus, zooming

I have an image inside of my web view. The image is so big and I've enabled scrolls but the problem is that I want to set default view (first look on image before doing scroll or zoom ) to specific part of image. Any idea ?

```
            WebView callUsView2= (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.callUsView2); 

            WebSettings callUsView2Setting = callUsView2.getSettings();

            callUsView2Setting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            callUsView2Setting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            callUsView2.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            callUsView2.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            callUsView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.png");
```

Result >

[image]

What I want >

[image]

ANSWER >>

```
                callUsView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                    if ( view.getProgress()==100) {
                        // I save Y w/in Bundle so orientation changes [in addition to
                        // initial loads] will reposition to last location
                        jumpToY(1000 , 1800 );
                    }
                }


                private void jumpToY (final int xLocation , final int yLocation ) {
                callUsView2.postDelayed( new Runnable () {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        callUsView2.scrollTo(xLocation, yLocation);
                      }
                  }, 300);
                }


             } );
```

Comment: Maybe do your zoom, before the image is displayed? Hide your WebView and when you ready reveal it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean!?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you wish to zoom before the user see the map. Is that true?

Comment: In fact no ,I want to set view to specific part of image for example (100,20)  not (0,0)! As I mentioned image is big and I want to show specific part of it at the beginning ...

Comment: Oh My topic is wrong ... :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is big and you want to show a specific part, you may want to zoom and scroll to a specific part.
What you can do is for example change the scale:

```
callUsView2.setInitialScale(some value which fits your needs);
```

and scroll if you wish to change the position:

```
callUsView2.scrollTo(x,y);
```

Comment: It seems to be true but using this line 

callUsView2.scrollTo(840,1200);  

didn't change anything

Comment: I think this answer might help you with the current problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392031/webview-scrollto-is-not-working

Comment: I found the answer here. Thanks to @Udi l http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737412/android-webview-scrollto-is-not-working