# Webview not start at top inside nestedscrollview

Tags: android, webview, android-nestedscrollview

I made a simple webview app which holds webview inside nestedscrollview. When I took to Facebook and scroll to the bottom and click on see more stories. Next page starts at bottom or middle, not at the top.

What to do? I don't want to remove nestedscrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <WebView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

MainActivitiy.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,
            int newProgress) {

        if (newProgress >= 100) {

            webView.scrollTo(0,0);
        }

        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    };

});
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
  { super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    view.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});

    webView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
         webView.scrollTo(0, 0);

    }
});

    }
}
```

Comment: no bro. I already checked

Answer (score 0):

This particular answer contains the information you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392142/2698179

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

  }
);
```

Will scroll to 0,0 on the site when the page is finished loading, but is apparently unreliable, the answer contains an alternative:

```
webView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
         webView.scrollTo(0, 0);

    }
});
```

Either one of these will move the webview to the top left of the page when loading is complete.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? What doesn't work? It doesn't compile at all? You get an error? Nothing happens?

Comment: I added your code. but it still webview not start at the top.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code as you have it now?

Comment: when I add code. they show "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon"  Why is that

Comment: Probably because all of your lines of code are not indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184416/discussion-between-keag-and-c49).